# Sendgrid webhook response is not receiving in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sendgrid, webhooks

I am new in ruby on rails and I am working on sendgrid event webhooks for email.
I have successfully integrated email sending system but Now I want to track email events.

I have setup a controller and method with post route to receive the webhook response.

When I directly hit the link every thing works fine but when i try to test it using sendgrid webhook testing tool nothing happened. I dont know what is wrong with it. No error is showing on site or in my logs.

Here is my route

```
post 'apis/email_events', :to => 'apis#email_events'
```

Testing tool url for endpoint

```
http://localhost:8090/apis/email_events
```

controller code

```
class ApisController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
    require 'json'

def email_events
    email = params["_json"][0]["email"]
    event  = params["_json"][0]["event"]
    time = params["_json"][0]["timestamp"]
    EmailInvite.create(email:email,status:event)
end
```

end

When I hit the same endpoint using postman with json response every thing works fine and I got record in database but using sendgrid test tool it is not working.

```
[
  {
    "email":"john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337197600,
    "smtp-id":"<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>",
    "sg_event_id":"sendgrid_internal_event_id",
    "sg_message_id":"sendgrid_internal_message_id",
    "event": "processed"
  },
  {
    "email":"john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "ip":"X.XX.XXX.XX",
    "sg_event_id":"sendgrid_internal_event_id",
    "url":"https://sendgrid.com",
    "sg_message_id":"sendgrid_internal_message_id",
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",
    "event":"click"
  },
  {
    "ip": "X.XX.XXX.XX",
    "sg_user_id": 123,
    "sg_event_id":"sendgrid_internal_event_id",
    "sg_message_id":"sendgrid_internal_message_id",
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",
    "event": "group_unsubscribe",
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337969592,
    "asm_group_id": 42
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify... Are you asking why clicking a link on the internet cannot reach `localhost`?

Comment: @TomLord I think you have not read my question carefully. I am new to ruby not new in programming. I have described that postman is hitting my endpoint but sendgrid tool is not working. is this clear or not?

Comment: Postman in running locally on your machine, so of course it can access `localhost`. Sendgrid is an external tool on the internet, so of course it cannot access `localhost`. Unless I'm missing something, the reason why this isn't working is fairly simple... But how have you configured sendgrid??

Comment: Have you tried looking into using any tools like [this](https://sendgrid.com/blog/test-webhooks-ngrok/)? Although this is not strictly needed; developers will often rely on a QA/Staging server for checking "real" web calls from SendGrid.

Comment: yeah I know about ngrok. Please let me check and stay online. I will get back to you.

Comment: @TomLord Thanks a lot. It works and I have learnt a new thing today.Thanks buddy.